Gap between labels of the axes and the arrowheads
I have posted a question Doing a graph using mathematica in this site few hours ago and I got a nice answer too.
I tried some modifications of the codes and got satisfied with the output. Here is the modified codes.
Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.03}],
PlotRange -> {{-0.65, 0.65}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0.5, 
Ticks -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.5], Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/3]},
AxesLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}]

Here is the output:

It looks very nice to me and happy of course because I started studying mathematica a few days ago and here I am I was able to generate graphs using mathematica with the help of some comments and suggestions of members of this site.
My Question:
I'm just curious if there is a way that the labels can be made closer to the arrowheads?
Any tips?

I have no answer to your question, but {-0.65, 0.65} in PlotRange looks weird. Automatic or Full or {-1,1} is more natural. Also I prefer to use option AspectRatio -> Automatic in such a plot.

You can use "Epilog" instead of "AxesLabel" to control the labels inside the plot
Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -1, 1}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.03}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.65, 0.65}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.5,
      Ticks -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.5], Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/3]}, 
     AxesLabel -> {None, None}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}, 
     Epilog -> {Text[Style["x-axis", 14], {1.02, -0.4}], 
       Text[Style["y-axis", 14], {0.2, Pi/2 + 0.2}]}]


